# Express api fetch request returns undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api

Edit:  I don't ask anything about cors here

So I have spent hours trying to figure out what's goin on, and well ... I'm losing it...

So I have this simple app that has the server part made in nodejs and the front end in react, they run on diferent ports so I used cors module.

Anyway
So this is my nodejs api using express

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({data:"Hello"});
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

and then from react the following fetch request

```
    fetch("http://www.localhost:5000/",{
        method: 'GET',
        mode: "no-cors",
        cache: "no-cache", 
        credentials: "same-origin", 
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
      })
    .then(res=>{
        console.log("res1",res)
        res.text();
    })
    .then(res=>{
        console.log("res2",res)
    })
    .catch(res=>{
        console.log("Exception : ",res);
    })
```

The thing is this req returns undefined whatever I try.
In res 1 the response is an object ( in this case opaque )

> Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok:
>   false, …}

And well res2 is undefined.

What am I missing ?

Comment: You need to return a value for each `then` call for it to be passed down.

Comment: if you are not asking about CORS, why have you tagged your question so? Tag only with what you are asking *about*, not with what your question *contains*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetch("http://www.localhost:5000/",{
        method: 'GET',
        mode: "no-cors",
        cache: "no-cache", 
        credentials: "same-origin", 
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
      })
    .then(res=>{
        console.log("res1",res)
        return res.text();
    })
    .then(res=>{
        console.log("res2",res)

    })
    .catch(res=>{
        console.log("Exception : ",res);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you.. I'm tired .. and maybe stupid ... my question was stupid ... apologies

Comment: All good.  No question is stupid here.  Happy to help.  Please do mark answer as accepted so that others benefit from it.